# Dicionários de traduções devem usar as strings originais como chaves?

Tags: localização, i18n

Já construí alguns sistemas e sites multilíngues, e nas ferramentas que conheci parece haver uma tendência a se utilizar a *string* no idioma original da aplicação (geralmente inglês) como chave para as respectivas traduções.

Por exemplo, num arquivo POT do [`gettext`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/):

```
msgid "My name is %s.\n"
msgstr "Meu nome é %s.\n"
```

Dessa maneira, com o `gettext`, um código hipotético deveria ser alterado de

```
printf("My name is %s.\n", nome);
```

para

```
printf(_("My name is %s.\n"), nome);
```

O `gettext` tem até uma ferramenta que varre o código procurando chamadas da função `_`, e gera o arquivo POT no formato acima, faltando somente preencher o texto traduzido.

Tutoriais de outras ferramentas costumam induzir a práticas semelhantes. Porém o uso desse tipo de solução já me causou muitos problemas. Aqui no próprio Stack Overflow em Português, por exemplo. Toda vez que um texto qualquer é alterado no original em inglês, surge uma nova tradução pendente [no Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-pt/translate/#pt_BR/english), sem nenhuma referência à versão anterior do original ou da própria tradução. Isso causa muito trabalho duplicado, muita inconsistência, e potencialmente muito texto traduzido e não utilizado (por ter ficado defasado).

Me parece fazer mais sentido usar nomes mais significativos como chaves do dicionário, por exemplo `"CloseLinkText"` ou algo do tipo. Porém é muito raro ver alguém recomendar isso, ou mesmo ver softwares que usam esse tipo de chave.

#### Perguntas

- Existe algum bom motivo que justifique a disseminação dessa prática de usar as strings em inglês como chaves?
- Há alguma desvantagem grande, que eu estaria deixando de enxergar, em usar chaves que dêem um pouco mais de contexto sobre o que está sendo traduzido?
- Em suma, por que tantos sistemas internacionalizados transformam o trabalho de tradução em um pesadelo? Não existe alternativa melhor?

Comment: "Me parece fazer mais sentido usar nomes mais significativos [...]". O que é mais significativo do que o próprio texto no idioma original? Do jeito que você sugere, você só criou uma "coluna" a mais (equivalente a um novo idioma a ser manipulado). Aliás, lembrar tais "chaves" quando é necessário reusar uma string é muito mais difícil do que lembrar o texto original (e se o contra-argumento for automatização com listas de escolha, bom, por que não exibindo o texto original?). :)

Comment: Usar como chave o texto a traduzir leva a reutilização natural das frases já traduzidas. Os ficheiros PO e afins têm também "espaço" e costume de guardar mais contexto como comentário. Há tambem um grande volume de ferramentas que usam esses formatos (exemplo POedit, virtaal, translate-toolkit, omegat, etc),

Comment: @LuizVieira Você tem razão ao dizer que o próprio texto é auto-explicativo, em geral ele é mesmo (às vezes, quando é uma palavra solta, fica complicado entender o contexto). Eu acho que ter um identificador imutável evitaria outros problemas, mas como pouca gente faz isso deve ter alguma desvantagem muito grande. Seu argumento ainda não me convenceu :) Quanto a reusar strings que sejam o próprio texto, isso também tem seus próprios problemas – por exemplo, "read" (lido) em certos contextos precisaria ser "lidos", em outros precisaria ser "ler", e por aí vai...

Comment: É verdade, existem muitos problemas. Eu até acho que o pior não é a tradução, mas a localização propriamente dita (tamanho de texto em botões, por exemplo). De todas as formas, meu ponto é que o uso de chave não os resolveria. Esse seu exemplo é muito propício: ter chaves distintas para indicar singular e plural só é necessário se de fato a palavra ocorrer nos dois contextos. E o profissional responsável por fazer a localização vai precisar **necessariamente** considerar o contexto ao fazer a tradução (não somente o texto original, tampouco qualquer chave que você produza...)  :)

Comment: Em outras palavras: os problemas mencionados são um fato, mas eu desconheço bons argumentos que comprovem que o uso de chaves diferentes do texto original torne o processo de trabalho (que é a tradução propriamente dita e o reuso do texto pelos programadores) *efetivamente* melhor. De todas as formas, isso é só o meu *educated guess* (por isso só estou comentando, e não vou me atrever a responder...). :)

Comment: @bfavaretto estava tentando achar um meio de responder mas cai no mesmo problema já citado aqui, você provavelmente sabe mais disto do que eu, vou apenas acrescentar minha experiência que não deve ser diferente da sua e nada que ajude elucidar o problema. O que seria ótimo saber algo sobre isto. Tentou em inglês? Eu não faço porque não é fácil explicar e provavelmente teria que interagir bastante e não estou com paciência para gastar meu inglês "maravilhoso".

Comment: Não tentei em inglês, e pra falar a verdade desanimei um pouco da pergunta depois dos comentários do Luiz Vieira e da resposta abaixo. @bigown

Answer (score 3):

Se o idioma de quem está elaborando o programa é inglês, ou os desenvolvedores envolvidos conhecem bem o inglês, me parece muito mais produtivo e claro usar a mensagem original, "fingindo" que outros idiomas não existem.

No exemplo específico que você deu, você consegue ver as máscaras, o que é importante (se o número de máscaras for maior que o número de parâmetros adicionais do printf(), o programa vai quebrar). Este é um bom motivo.

Localização/internacionalização é sempre um pesadelo. Os maiores problemas são: tamanho que a mensagem traduzida vai ocupar na interface de usuário, e diferenças culturais/de jargão que o tradutor pode ignorar, e se você não conhece um pouco do idioma traduzido, não tem nem como verificar.

Não acho que o POT seja o pior esquema, nem tampouco provoca nem resolve os grandes problemas da localização acima citados. Se a mensagem original for mudada, pelo menos isto fica explícito (pois pode ser detectado automaticamente no build).

No Android, onde é costumeiro usar labels R.id. em vez das strings originais, ocorre o problema oposto: alguém muda a mensagem original em inglês, as traduções continuam valendo mas talvez elas não sejam mais adequadas ao novo tamanho que a nova mensagem ocupa na interface de usuário, ou talvez a nova mensagem seja completamente diferente, e manter as traduções velhas é desvantagem.

Reconheço que uma vantagem do label em vez da string em inglês original é quando uma mesma mensagem é utilizada em diferentes contextos (menu e título, por exemplo), e talvez a tradução tenha de ser menos prolixa no menu pois o espaço disponível é menor.