# Sistema de texto do site

Tags: php, html, txt

Estou fazendo um site que terá suporte para várias línguas, porém o que mais dificulta é o método de tradução de cada palavra/frase do site. No caso eu estava pensando em fazer um sistema onde as palavras ficarão em um arquivo .txt e atribuir elas por códigos exemplo:

```
NOME.DO.SITE=Meu Site
CODIGO.1=Texto/Frase
```

Mas não queria colocar dentro de uma chamada PHP, e sim apenas o código (NOME.DO.SITE): o sistema PHP identificava o código do site no arquivo .txt e o substitui pela sua Palavra/Frase (Meu Site).

Se alguém souber com fazer esse sistema, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Dá uma olhada em https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4682800/how-to-use-po-pot-files-with-php

Comment: Pesquise sobre internacionalização com PHP, alguns frameworks de php como o Laravel já tratam isso.

Comment: Relacionada: [Dicionários de traduções devem usar as strings originais como chaves?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/64589/)